# Classic Hand shake question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am asked the following question:

> My wife and I were invited to a party attended by four other
>   husband-wife couples, making a total of ten people. As people arrived,
>   there was some hand shaking. No one shook their own hand, and there
>   were no husband-wife hand shakes. When it was over, I asked each
>   person "How many people did you shake hands with?" I asked nine people
>   (not including myself) and got nine different answers. How many people
>   did my wife shake hands with?

Since there are 10 people in the room should I use the formula `n(n-1)2`, which results in `10(10-1)/2=45` which would be the sum of all the handshakes. If I divide that by ten I would get 4.5 people shook his wife's hand.

This doesn't seem correct at all. What is the right direction to head in order to solve this question?

EDIT:

I ended up trying to solve by pairing everyone together and drawing a graph showing the relations between everyone:[image]

But this wasn't complete apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  No person shook more than eight hands, so you must have gotten answers from 0 to 8 inclusive.  Who is married to the person who shook 8?

Comment: Did she shake 4 hands?

Comment: @Nick:  yes, she did.

Comment: I do not see how she shook 4 hands. Why could no one have shaken 0 hands? He got answers from 0 to 8 inclusive right?

Comment: @jmi4:  yes, somebody shook 0 hands.  The person who shook 8 had to shake with everybody except his/her spouse, who must be the person who shook 0.  The the ones that shook 7 and 1 are married.  It keeps going, with each couple summing to 8.  That requires two 4's.  To avoid getting two like answers, he must be one of the two and his wife the other.

Comment: @RossMillikan can you take a look at my edits. I didn't end up getting the answer the proper way could you expand on your answer so I can see the proper way. My full hw is [here][1]   

[1]:https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16641927/hw6.jpg

Comment: @Nick:  your graph seems to reflect the point of my answer to jmi4.  You correctly pair H5 with W5 as the person who shook 8 must be married to the person who shook 0.  Then you pair H4 with W4 as the 7 and 1, going on to your wife with 4.  What do you mean not the proper way?

Comment: I'm not sure, my professor gave me a 6 out of 10 on the homework. So I assumed I did something incorrect. I thought maybe there was a  better math representation of the answer versus my graphical one

Comment: @Nick: I think it is difficult to follow.  I knew what to look for based on our discussion.  If I were doing it, I would write up the logic of my last two comments, rather than the diagram.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The answer lies in the question itself.
It says, there were no hand shakes between husband-wife and the man asking everyone has not included himself in the count, so he and his wife would not be counted.
Therefore the answer is 8...His wife shook hands with 8 people(excluding her husband).

Comment: Who shook 0 then?

Comment: No.if his wife shook 8 hands, she shook hands with everybody except her husband. Nobody shook 0 hands so there must be two people who shook the same number.

Comment: How? any explanation?

Comment: Yes, you're right Ross

Comment: It sounds like you are reading it that everybody shook all hands except their spouse's. Then each person would shake 8. But then when he asked how many hands people shook, all answers would be the same.