# Trivia math question

Tags: graph-theory

I invite 10 couples to a party to my house. I ask everyone present, including my wife, how many people they shook hands with. It turns out that everyone questioned - I didn't question myself of course - shook hands with a different number of people. If we assume that no one shook hands with his or her partner, how many people did my wife shake hands with?

I was thinking around 4.

Comment: You might look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206668/classic-hand-shake-question) which is for a different number of people.

Comment: I dislike questions like this.  Instead of asking the question directly, it is rephrased into a contrived and ambiguously worded question, and we're left to decipher the author's intended meaning.  (a) *Contrived*:  Didn't you just ask your wife how many people she just shook hands with?  (b) *Ambiguous*: Did all 10 couples attend the party?

Comment: This question had been given in the book, Art and craft of problem solving by Paul Zeitz.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Interpret this situation as a graph.

Have a vertex for each person, and each edge is a handshake.

Consider the degree of each vertex. In particular the relation between the degree of someone and the degree of their partner.