# Modified hand shake problem

Tags: graph-theory, combinations

Question-A couple invites $n – 1$ other couples to dinner. once everyone arrives, each person shakes hands with everyone he doesn’t know. Then, the host asks everyone how many hands they shook and each person replies with a different number. Assuming that everyone knows his or her own spouse, how many hands did the hostess shake?

This is a question of combinatorics I tried thinking logically about this and using multiplicative principal but couldn't solve it

Comment: Pretty well known problem, think of the people as points and consider a graph

Comment: Actually I am not aware of this method

Comment: Check out the following link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206668/classic-hand-shake-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the answer from the following link- [Classic Hand shake question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206668/classic-hand-shake-question). Now then, also if you didn't understand the answer then I might give a better explanation. We can easily see that there were in total of 2n members in the party inclusive the host couple. All 2n-1 people gave a different reply for the number of handshake. So, all answers from 0 to 2n-2 would show the number of handshake for different people (which are in total 2n-1). Now, take an assumption that if the husband doesn't know anyone then the wife will know her and vice versa. So, sum of handshake of each husband and wife would come out to be 2n-2. Now placing different values can cover all the constraints for the question. The first husband handshake 2n-2 people and his wife, 0 people. Then the next husband handshake 2n-1 people and his wife 1 person. All vales would be covered. But only in a single pair of husband and wife, both will shake hand with n-1 people((2n-2)/2). But this can only be possible if this pair of husband and wife is of the host. So, the host asked all other people and hence his own case would not be considered. So, the hostess shook hands with n-1 people. Hope my solution is clear enough for you. Please increase my reputation!!